# What's up with the weird word order in 乞うご期待?

Tags: expressions

乞うご期待 is a set expression that means "Don't miss it!"

What's up with the weird word order? If I interpret this to really mean ご期待を乞う, then I can't think of any other circumstance in Japanese where the object of a main verb can *follow* the verb.

Comment: プログレッシブ和英中辞典(第３版) gives it as [`乞う，ご期待`](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E8%AB%8B%E3%81%86) so I don't think your theory works

Comment: I think my question still stands. Verb-fronting, especially in the register implied by ご- is not expected.

Comment: English has [similar examples](https://www.thoughtco.com/hyperbaton-figure-of-speech-1690940).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From today's perspective, it might as well be called a sample of anastrophe. However, not many words other than 乞う use this type of formula.

Etymologically, it comes from a specific practice in the [漢文訓読](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanbun) tradition. There is a Chinese verb 請 "treat" that is also used as if English "please". This "interjectory" 請 is often read out at the original place instead of brought after the object.

> 請息交以絕游
> 請【こ】う　交【まじ】わりを息【や】めて　以【もっ】て游【ゆう】を絶【た】たん（[帰去来辞](https://kanbun.info/syubu/kikyorainoji.html)）
>
> 請君爲我傾耳聽
> 請【こ】う君【きみ】　我【わ】が為【ため】に耳【みみ】を傾【かたむ】けて聴【き】け（[将進酒](http://www5a.biglobe.ne.jp/%7Eshici/rs61.htm)）

The 乞う～ expression is the remnant of this construction, normally with homonymous 乞 instead of correct 請.

Comment: そうそう・・漢文調かな～と思ってたのよ。。

Comment: This is it! I'm glad you're on the site @broccoli!

Comment: Wow that makes a lot of sense. So just as Chinese starts a request with 請 (qǐng), used similarly to the way English speakers start a request with 'Please', this is also directly translated into Japanese by putting '請う' first. Interesting! Wow, Kanbun is really tricky...

Answer (score 1):

I think the headline is used [「倒置法」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%80%92%E7%BD%AE) and [「体言止め」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BF%AE%E8%BE%9E%E6%8A%80%E6%B3%95#%E4%BD%93%E8%A8%80%E6%AD%A2%E3%82%81)・[「喚体句」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%96%9A%E4%BD%93%E5%8F%A5) i.e.「ご期待を乞う」→ 「乞うご期待」.

The author using the figure of speech to emphasize the author's "wish": 「乞う」 and the reverberation of 「体言止め」 is actually sustaining "anticipation" : 「御期待」.

「乞うご期待」seems to have started to be expressed as 「乞御期待」 in the advertisement of the movie currently showing at the theater.

「乞うご期待」: *I very wish you guys really look forward to for the next time*

[image]